# How to use addNew api in lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013, lightswitch-2012

Now I started working on *lightswith* application but I can't achieve *crud* operation light through api `addNew()` method like as

```
screen.table.addNew()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the HTML client, the function can be used in the following way for an entity set named Customers, with a string property named Name:

```
var customer = screen.Customers.addNew();
customer.Name = "TestCustomer";
myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.saveChanges();
```

Unless you're setting an entity that the framework will be saving (such as the element on an addEdit screen), you need to save it with the saveChanges or commitChanges functions.